# "Other" classification for epitopes in the Immune Epitope Database (IEDB)

Tags: bioinformatics, proteins

I used the [immune epitope database](http://www.iedb.org/result_v3.php?cookie_id=0ebfde) (IEDB) to search for epitopes. I found some epitopes derived from antigens called " other" by IEDB.  When I asked about it,  the answer was "*We use the "other" category to group epitopes from the same species that only BLAST match to GenBank entries that are nonhomologous to the reference proteome*".

Could someone explain this?

Comment: Welcome to BiologySE @Shad... you've got some abbreviations and technical language that may make it a bit hard for some individuals to follow... you may want to edit it a big (explain some more things) and visit the help center for additional pointers - thanks for your efforts and contribution http://biology.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I've done what @VanceLAlbaugh suggested for you as I have edit privileges. Good titles make questions more useful to other uses and increase your chances of getting an appropriate answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I presume that these epitopes represent peptides that have been eluted from MHC molecules and then sequenced by mass spec.  You can then compare these peptide sequences to a reference genome (more specifically to the proteins predicted to arise from the reference genome).  If the peptide matches perfectly to a predicted protein, then you assign it that identify.

But many peptides will not align to the predicted proteins, and so they can't be unambiguously assigned a gene of origin.

There are many reasons why MHC-derived peptides may not match the proteome.  Most obviously, the reference genomes are typically from a single individual, so if the sequenced peptide has a SNP, or other allelic variation, it won't line up.  As well, a significant number of peptides undergo some form of modification during antigen processing, such as deglycosylation changing Asn to Asp, proteasome-mediated cleavage and re-annealing, and so on.  These modified peptides also won't line up to the predicted proteome.